# visual studio cyrillic text c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013, running on windows 7 64 bit.
I am trying to display a language different than English. My code is:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>



using namespace std;

typedef char byte;
byte text[] = "текст";

int text_len;

struct Huf {
    byte id;
    int wh;
    Huf *left, *right;
};

struct List {
    List *next;
    Huf *tree;
};

List *head;
char code[256];

void createList();
void writeList();
void delList(List *);
void addList(Huf *);
Huf *findDels();
void createTree();
void rlrootTree(Huf *, unsigned);

int main()
{
    text_len = strlen(text);
    createList();
    writeList();
    createTree();
    cout << "writeCodes\n";
    rlrootTree(head->tree, 0);
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void createList()
{
    int i;
    int ch[256] = { 0 };
    for (i = 0; i<text_len; i++) ch[text[i]]++;
    List *l;
    Huf *h;
    head = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<255; i++) if (ch[i]>0)
    {
        h = new Huf;
        h->id = i; h->wh = ch[i];
        h->left = 0; h->right = 0;
        l = new List;
        l->tree = h;
        l->next = head; head = l;
    }
}

void writeList()
{
    cout << "writeList\n";
    List *l = head;
    while (l)
    {
        cout << (l->tree)->id << " ";
        l = l->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
    l = head;
    while (l)
    {
        cout << (l->tree)->wh << " ";
        l = l->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void delList(List *l)
{
    List *lp, *lc;
    if (l == head) { head = l->next; delete l; }
    else
    {
        lp = head; lc = lp->next;
        while (lc != l) { lp = lc; lc = lc->next; }
        lp->next = lc->next; delete lc;
    }
}

void addList(Huf *h)
{
    List *l = new List;
    l->tree = h;
    l->next = head;
    head = l;
}

Huf *findDels()
{
    List *l = head, *sm = head;
    Huf *h;
    while (l)
    {
        if ((l->tree)->wh < (sm->tree)->wh) sm = l;
        l = l->next;
    }
    h = sm->tree;
    delList(sm);
    return h;
}

void createTree()
{
    Huf *h, *h1, *h2;
    while (head->next)
    {
        h1 = findDels();
        h2 = findDels();
        h = new Huf;
        h->id = ' '; h->wh = h1->wh + h2->wh;
        h->left = h1; h->right = h2;
        addList(h);
    }
}

void rlrootTree(Huf *h, unsigned index)
{
    if (h)
    {
        code[index] = '0';
        rlrootTree(h->right, index + 1);
        if (h->left == 0)
        {
            code[index] = '\0';
            cout << h->id << "->" << code << " ";
        }
        code[index] = '1';
        rlrootTree(h->left, index + 1);
    }
}
```

I have tried adding `<locale>` and `<windows.h>` includes with `AnsiToOem()` but it doesnt seem to compile - I get character errors.

Comment: Did I miss something about cyrylic? Why would you need *that* much code to write a text to the console?

Comment: I am doing a huffman tree and i want to do it with a text in cyrillic if I want to just display cyrillic it is easy #include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
 char example[] = "Текст на кирилица";
 AnsiToOem(example, example);
 cout << example << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

Comment: Please give the text of the errors you are receiving in the question.

Comment: Please, reduce your code to contain only things that are relevant to your question. And don't post code in comments.

Comment: What encoding is used to save your source file?

Comment: Visual C++ / Source.pp

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the text byte by byte. But each letter (*grapheme*) consists of two code units, that is two bytes.

To make this simple I would store the string as an array of char32_t, because then the whole codepoint (one grapheme) would fit in one element of the array.

If you want to be able to handle absolutely every international "character" you would also have to handle *grapheme clusters* then you would have have a look at the ICU library or similar.

A dangerously simplified suggestion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

typedef char32_t byte;
byte text[] = U"текст";

int text_len;

struct Huf {
  byte id;
  int wh;
  Huf *left, *right;
};

struct List {
  List *next;
  Huf *tree;
};

List *head;
char code[16000];

void createList();
void writeList();
void delList(List *);
void addList(Huf *);
Huf *findDels();
void createTree();
void rlrootTree(Huf *, unsigned);

unsigned strlen(char32_t* st) {
  unsigned len = 0;
  while (*(st+len) != 0) ++len;
  return len;
}

int main()
{
  text_len = strlen(text);
  std::cout << "len = " << text_len << std::endl;
  createList();
  writeList();
  createTree();
  cout << "writeCodes\n";
  rlrootTree(head->tree, 0);
  cout << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void createList() 
{
  int i;
  int ch[16000] = { 0 }; //you really need more here
  for (i = 0; i<text_len; i++) ch[text[i]]++;
  List *l;
  Huf *h;
  head = 0;
  for (i = 0; i<16000; i++) if (ch[i]>0)
  {
    h = new Huf;
    h->id = i; h->wh = ch[i];
    h->left = 0; h->right = 0;
    l = new List;
    l->tree = h;
    l->next = head; head = l;
  }
}

void writeList()
{
  cout << "writeList\n";
  List *l = head;
  while (l)
  {
    cout << (l->tree)->id << " ";
    l = l->next;
  }
  cout << endl;
  l = head;
  while (l)
  {
    cout << (l->tree)->wh << " ";
    l = l->next;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void delList(List *l)
{
  List *lp, *lc;
  if (l == head) { head = l->next; delete l; }
  else
  {
    lp = head; lc = lp->next;
    while (lc != l) { lp = lc; lc = lc->next; }
    lp->next = lc->next; delete lc;
  }
}

void addList(Huf *h)
{
  List *l = new List;
  l->tree = h;
  l->next = head;
  head = l;
}

Huf *findDels()
{
  List *l = head, *sm = head;
  Huf *h;
  while (l)
  {
    if ((l->tree)->wh < (sm->tree)->wh) sm = l;
    l = l->next;
  }
  h = sm->tree;
  delList(sm);
  return h;
}

void createTree()
{
  Huf *h, *h1, *h2;
  while (head->next)
  {
    h1 = findDels();
    h2 = findDels();
    h = new Huf;
    h->id = ' '; h->wh = h1->wh + h2->wh;
    h->left = h1; h->right = h2;
    addList(h);
  }
}

void rlrootTree(Huf *h, unsigned index)
{
  if (h)
  {
    code[index] = '0';
    rlrootTree(h->right, index + 1);
    if (h->left == 0)
    {
      code[index] = '\0';
      cout << h->id << "->" << code << " ";
    }
    code[index] = '1';
    rlrootTree(h->left, index + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: When i try to use wchar_t instead of unsigned char i get `Error 1 error C2371: 'byte' : redefinition; different basic types c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\test11\test11\source.cpp 10 1 test11
 2 IntelliSense: a value of type "const char [18]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "byte []" c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\test11\test11\Source.cpp 11 15 test11
`

Comment: Have you tried the exact code I use here? It uses the c++11 type char32_t  which is actually enough to represent a complete codepoint (which normally is a complete "letter")

Comment: Yes i am trying it now, even before compiling it i get  `1 IntelliSense: initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\test13\test13\Source.cpp 8 15 test13
 2 IntelliSense: expected a ';' c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\test13\test13\Source.cpp 8 16 test13`

I tried _TEXT(" ") but still the same

Comment: You could try `text[]= {'т', 'е', 'к', 'с', 'т'}` if your compiler doesn't handle the U"текст". It is also possible that you need to tell the compiler to use c++11 and not an older version.

Comment: It does compile like this, I am with vs2013 so i guess most of the features of c++11 are working, but it still doesnt work with the cyrillic text

Comment: @YordanChimev You don't get any output? I get `1082->000 1089->001 1077->01 1090->1` I do not know what output you expect. (And no - VS2013 doesn't support all c++11 features - and unicode literals are one of the things it is missing)

Comment: i am getting `Unhandled exception at 0x00D45593 in test13.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.` which I guess is due to the unicodes missing